# method with @Cacheable(forever = true) is still being called

Tags: java, caching, jcabi

I have this code:

```
import com.jcabi.aspects.Cacheable;

@Cacheable(forever = true)
public String authorizedRequestBuilder() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    return String.format("Bearer %s", acquireToken());
}
```

while debugging I see the method's body is called few times.

Is there any more config to do?

Comment: Did you check if it reaches `String.format("Bearer %s", acquireToken())` as well?  Might be that a Proxy is used in background and that method call still happens but on the Proxy which delegates to the cache.

Comment: not sure i follow. The whole method should be called because of the annotation no? regardless of its body

Comment: @EladBenda2 not really, the result will be cached only if there are no exceptions. If your method throws an exception, there is nothing to cache. Also, are you sure your binaries are weaved? See http://aspects.jcabi.com/example-aspectj.html

Comment: here is the signature  `private String acquireToken() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {` but when i debugged no exception was thrown and still the body was called again

Comment: Im not familiar with jcabi but any cache must have some sort of memory restrictions, and when there is no space left, stuff can be evicted disregarding `forever = true`.

Answer (score 0):

**jcabi** [only works with AspectJ compile time weaving.](http://aspects.jcabi.com/index.html)

So have you made sure that you are using an AspectJ compiler to compile your code? As per [this blog post](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html), you should be using the jcabi Maven plugin (or equivalent):

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>ajc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```